# Enviar email php ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

no consigo que el email se envie, consigo por ajax recibir la alerta de confirmacion pero nada no se envia nada, status es 200 ok pero no funciona

```js
  $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    
    let nombre = $('#campoNombre').val();
    let email = $('#campoEmail').val();
    let telefono = $('#campoTelefono').val();
    let mensaje = $('#campoMensaje').val();
    
    if (nombre.length <= 2) {
      alertaError('El nombre es demasiado corto');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (email.includes('@') == false || email.includes('.') == false || email.indexOf('@') < 1) {
      alertaError('El email no es correcto');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (telefono.length < 9) {
      alertaError('El telefono debe tener al menos 9 numeros');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    else if (mensaje.length <= 10) {
      alertaError('El mensaje es demasiado corto');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(datos) {
          let texto = datos.saludo + '<br>' + datos.mensaje;
          msg(texto, 2);
        }
        
      });
      
      //Empty field info except button
      $('input:not(.boton), textarea').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
      });
    }
    
  });
  
});

//ERROR MSG
function alertaError(texto){
  $('#alerta p').text(texto);
  $('#alerta').addClass('visible');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#alerta').removeClass('visible');
  },3000);
}

// MSG
function msg(mensajes, tiempo) {
  
  $('#alerta p').html(mensajes);
  
  $('#alerta').addClass('visible');
  
  setTimeout( function(){
    $('#alerta').removeClass('visible');
  },tiempo * 2000);
}
```

```css
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  $jsondata = array();

     $jsondata['saludo'] = '¡Hola '. $_POST['campoNombre'] . '!';

     $jsondata['mensaje'] = 'Nos pondremos en contacto contigo lo antes posible';


  header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($jsondata);
  exit();



  if($_POST) {
      $to_Email       = "fmls1989@gmail.com"; // email de recepción
      $subject        = 'SOLICITUD DE CONTACTO'; // asunto

      // saneado de seguridad
      $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["campoNombre"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["campoEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["campoTelefono"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      // composición de email
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=charset=UTF-8";
      $headers .= 'From: SOLICITUD DE CONTACTO' . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

      $body = "Se ha recibido una nueva solicitud de contacto:"."\r\n";
      $body .= "Nombre: " . $user_Name ."\r\n";
      $body .= "Correo: " . $user_Email ."\r\n";
      $body .= "Mensaje: " . $user_Message ."\r\n";


      // envío de email
      $sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $body, $headers);

    // if($sentMail)
    // {
    //   header('Location: contact.php');
    //   //PROBAR METER AJAX CON JS sin mandar a pagina, con alerta en la misma pagina
    // }

  }


?>
```

```html
 <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="formulario">
                              <div class="row">
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <input id="campoNombre" name="campoNombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre...">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <input id="campoEmail" name="campoEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email...">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <input id="campoTelefono" name="campoTelefono" type="tel" placeholder="Telefono...">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <textarea id="campoMensaje" name="campoMensaje" type="text" placeholder="Mensaje..." rows="8" maxlength="999"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="boton">
                                </div>
                                
                              </div>
                              
                            </form>
```

Comment: Quita o comenta la línea **exit();** porque detiene la ejecución del script.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en PHP: Debe quitar la linea `exit();`  y en el código `$headers` es suficiente con que vaya así:

```
$headers = 'From: fmls1989@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

Debe indicarse de que cuenta de correo sale.